# Load File/Asset in Robolectric Test which was created at Runtime

Tags: android, robolectric

My problem is the following: I have got a Robolectric Test case. The test case is creating a file in the test startup. Let me call this file Properties.txt.

The testcase itself will need this Properties.txt file. So I call:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
am.open(fileName);
```

The second line will lead to a FileNotFoundException. If I debug at this certain place I can see that the File is already created in the File System but Robolectric can not read the file.

So far so good, I think that's somehow logical. I assume Robolectric just loads a Reflection of the file system so it wont see runtime created files/assets.

Is it possible to somehow trigger a reload or enter an absolute path where Robolectric should always assume there is a file?

Answer (score 0):

Is this resource being created in assets folder?

Else you need to pass full path name trough a FileInputStream to read.

Comment: It is created in build/intermediates/assets/.

Comment: it is pre-created in the assets of the test or is created at runtime? AndroidStudio filepath is not the same one as Androids

Comment: As stated above the file is created during runtime. In the Setup method of the Test Class I create the file and would like to use it in the test methods.

Comment: So you need to get it trough the Full-file-system-path

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clarification. So it seems that this is not solveable for me as I am testing a function which is loading the file from the assets. I don't want to use a Full Path there. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Instead, receive a InputStream, so you can open either from File or from Assets